# Rest Api fetch additional data of entity

Tags: api, rest, url

When we need to fetch a sub resource of an entity, the best practice is to do:

```
 GET - todos/:id
```

But I can't find any information about best practices regarding fetching additional data about this resource. What is the best practice if I want to fetch the todos metrics data?

```
GET - todos/metrics
```

Is this the correct approach?

If so, it will not collide with `todos/:id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "one right" way to handle this.  Your suggestion is appropriate, but can be confused for a potential ID "metrics".  You can also use query parameters:

```
GET - todos/?metrics
```

or use a placeholder:

```
GET - todos/-/metrics
```

or, treat the metrics as a resource of it's own, so you actually are getting metrics, about the todos resource:

```
GET - metrics/todos
```

Anything here would be fine, so long as you're consistent across your resources.